# Named entity recognition with deep Learning model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

How to use named entity recognition using Deep Learning? I want to build a model using DL for named entity recognition.

Answer (score 1):

There are many pre-trained models/library for Named Entity Recognition(NER), you can use HuggingFace pre-traied modes, SpaCy and NLTK for the same.

If you want to go deep dive and train a Deep Learning model from scratch, you shall explore about BERT.
Also, I would recommend to go through Kaggle notebooks about Named Entity Recognition.